# IOS. enter data into a table (name and price of pizza) and view it on another view controller (in label)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

Have set up a class for the core data code to save and retrieve, then on the first view controller have a form to enter the price and name of the pizza, a save button to have the save method linked from the dbmanager, and a view button for viewing the saved data in the table.

now im not sure if my save method is correct but I have no errors for it yet. 
But i cant quite work out how to show the entered data in the table of the second view controllers label.

this is my first attempt on IOS

the first view controller:

```
 import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var price: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        let db = DatabaseManager()
        db.addRow(name: name.text!, price: price.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func view(_ sender: Any) {
       let db = DatabaseManager()
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
            if segue.identifier == "mySegue" {
            let controller : allPizzas =      segue.destination as!  allPizzas
```

this line here below says cannot assign value of type [string] to string

```
controller.pizzaTxt = db.retrieveRows()

        }
    }


   `enter code here`// }

    func showMessage(msg: String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}




}
```

the second view controller:

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData
class allPizzas: UIViewController {


    //label to display the pizzas
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

    var pizzaTxt : String = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        output.text = pizzaTxt;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

the database manager:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DatabaseManager: NSObject {

    var pizzas: [NSManagedObject] = []
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    func addRow( name:String, price:String) {
        // set the core data to access the Student Entity
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Pizzas", in: managedContext)
        let pizza = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
        pizza.setValue(name,  forKey: "name")
        pizza.setValue(price, forKey: "price")
            do {
            try managedContext.save()
            pizzas.append(pizza)
             //showMessage(msg: "Information is added")
            }
            catch {
              //showMessage(msg: "Error While Adding to Core Data")
                }

    }



    func retrieveRows() -> [String] {  // return array of Strings
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return [""]}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Pizzas")
        do {
            pizzas  = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        }
        catch{
            // show something
        }
        var msg : [String] = []
        var count = 0
        for pizza in pizzas {
            msg.append((pizza.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String)!)
            count += 1
        }
          msg = [String(count)]
        return msg
    }




}
```

Comment: just a note: `prepareForSegue` is on the wrong level. it an posting error or this way in your code?

Comment: the error "cannot assign value of type [string] to string" is exactly what the error is. your `db.retrieveRows()` is a Array `[String]` and your property `controller.pizzaTxt` is type `String`